# Adding SBT as a dependency in SBT file

Tags: scala, sbt

I am writing few sbt tasks in a scala file. These SBT tasks will be imported into many other projects.

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      organization := "com.example",
      scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
      version      := "1.0.0"
    )),
    name := "sbttasks",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scala-sbt" % "sbt" % "1.0.0" % "provided"
    )
  )
```

I get a compilation error

```
error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml, org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators
[error]         at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.ConflictWarning$.processCrossVersioned(ConflictWarning.scala:39)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.ConflictWarning$.apply(ConflictWarning.scala:19)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$ivyBaseSettings$64(Defaults.scala:1995)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:39)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:66)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:262)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:271)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:262)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:174)
[error]         at sbt.Completion
```

I don't want to write the custom tasks in build.sbt itself (as the SBT documentation shows) because then I won't be able to import my custom tasks into other projects.

Comment: Why do you need sbt as a dependency? Even if it's really what you want, sbt 1.0 uses Scala 2.12, and your project uses Scala 2.11, so that may cause problems.

Comment: Because I have source code `src/mainscala/com/mytasks/Tasks.scala` this file contains code which has custom tasks. I will import these custom tasks into many other projects.

Comment: Do you mean subprojects or you're making an sbt plugin? Depending on what you actually want, I will tell you how to achieve it. In any case you don't need to have sbt as an explicit dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write reusable tasks that you can "import" in different projects, you need to make an [sbt plugin](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Using-Plugins.html).

If you have a [multi-project build](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Multi-Project.html) and want to reuse your tasks in the subprojects, you can create a file `project/MyPlugin.scala` with

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object MyPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  override def trigger = noTrigger

  object autoImport {
    val fooTask = taskKey[Foo]("Foo description")
    val barTask = taskKey[Bar]("Bar description")
  }
  import autoImport._

  override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
    fooTask := { ??? },
    barTask := { ??? }
  )
}
```

Then to enable this plugin (i.e. make those tasks available) in a subproject, you can write this in your `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val subproject = (project in file("subproject"))
  .enablePlugins(MyPlugin)
```

---

On the contrast, if you want to reuse these tasks in other unrelated projects, you need to make this plugin a separate project and publish it. It's a normal sbt project, but instead of an explicit sbt dependency, you write in its `build.sbt`:

```
sbtPlugin := true
```

And the code defining tasks goes to `src/main/scala/` (like in a normal project).

You can read in detail about writing plugins in the [sbt documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Plugins.html).

Answer (score 0):

Change version of **"org.scala-sbt" to "1.0.0-M4"**

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      organization := "com.example",
      scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
      version      := "1.0.0",
      name := "sbttasks"
    )),
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.scala-sbt" % "sbt" % "1.0.0-M4" % "provided"
    )
  )
```

For entire compatibility matrix check 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/main